# SVG background of div cant stick to bottom in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

Yello,

Have been trying to figure this problem out for a while, asked a friend, a developer collegue.. No succes. Maybe one of you knows the answer?

I use an SVG image as background for my header:

CSS:

```
header {
height:200px;
width:100%;
background-image: url("../img/header.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:0% 100%;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header id="header"></header>
```

In every browser it displays perfectly but in IE(11) there is a space between the header and content on small screen sizes, the gap differs. I use Bootstraps responsive classes.

[image: SVG IE gap]

Comment: On actual small screen devices is the gap there? Just reducing your IE11 browser is not a true representation of how the website will render on a small screen device. Unless that device is running IE11, but even then chances are it will be different per device.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I know indeed, but I still want to make sure it works as it is suppose to work in every browser. Even when i make the browser window as big as a small desktop there is still a small gap.. :(